# How to save file on local of the Pepper

Tags: python-2.7, nao-robot, pepper

```
ALMEMORY_KEY_NAMES = [
"Device/SubDeviceList/HeadYaw/Position/Actuator/Value", 
"Device/SubDeviceList/HeadYaw/Position/Sensor/Value",
"Device/SubDeviceList/HeadYaw/ElectricCurrent/Sensor/Value", 
"Device/SubDeviceList/HeadYaw/Temperature/Sensor/Value",
"Device/SubDeviceList/HeadYaw/Hardness/Actuator/Value",
"Device/SubDeviceList/HeadYaw/Temperature/Sensor/Status",]

ROBOT_IP = "10.34.111.131"

import os
import sys
import time

from naoqi import ALProxy

def recordData(nao_ip):

    print "Recording data ..."
    memory = ALProxy("ALMemory", nao_ip, 9559)
    data = list()
    for i in range (1, 500):
        line = list()
        for key in ALMEMORY_KEY_NAMES:
            value = memory.getData(key)
            line.append(value)
        data.append(line)
        time.sleep(0.005)
    return data


def main():

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        nao_ip = ROBOT_IP
    else:
        nao_ip = sys.argv[1]
    data = recordData(nao_ip)
    #output ="record.csv"
    output = ("/home/nao/.local/share/logkayit/logkayit.txt")

    with open(output, "w") as fp:
        for line in data:
            fp.write("; ".join(str(x) for x in line))
            fp.write("\n")

    print "Results written to", output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

First step: I want save also robot local `/home/nao/.local/share/logkayit/logkayit.txt`.
But it didnt work and I dont know what is solution.

Second step: I want save log about Dialog details also. I can check very well from Monitor App but I want it with `.cvs`.

Last step: is it possible to save that `.cvs` onTime? For example everyday 2 PM-4 PM

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code, it will print out the error - in your case, the problem is that the "data" variable doesn't exist, and *that* is because you are not calling the recordData function anywhere in your code.

Comment: You are right . I just forgot to put that line or wrongly delete dont know. I will edit code but still I have problem about that steps. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're not giving much information on what exactly doesn't work. Do you have logs ?

Comment: Yes I can access logs on PC. With output ="record.csv" code I can save logs as .csv on file of PC. I also want save it on robot like this code ;             
 output = ("/home/nao/.local/share/logkayit/logkayit.txt") it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you launch your code on your computer. If you want to write the logkayit.txt on the robot, you need to launch your .py on the robot. If not, your code will only try to write the txt file on your computer and raise an error.